# Listing packages that will be removed by "yum autoremove"?

Tags: ansible, centos, rpm, yum

```
Running CentOS 7.6
```

I am currently uninstalling Java in my kickstart post-install script *yum remove java-1.7**. When java is uninstalled, it orphans the *python-lxml* package which is then removed by a *yum autoremove -y* as it is now a leaf.

I then use ansible to do a bunch of configuration, which fails in a task that is trying to use "python-lxml".

Is there a way to list all of the packages "yum autoremove" will delete and mark them as *do not delete* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looking at the [repoquery API](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum-utils/blob/master/repoquery.py) and [package-cleanup man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/package-cleanup). Using `package-cleanup` I was able to list all the *leaves* on the system by passing the `--leaves` and `-all` flags. I then piped that input into `repoquery` to figure out which leaves were marked as a dependency. `--qf` allows me to specify the query format. Looking at the `repoquery` API I can see various api calls I can make.

```
querytags = [ 'name', 'version', 'release', 'epoch', 'arch', 'summary',
              'description', 'packager', 'url', 'buildhost', 'sourcerpm',
              'vendor', 'group', 'license', 'buildtime', 'filetime',
              'installedsize', 'archivesize', 'packagesize', 'repoid', 
              'requires', 'provides', 'conflicts', 'obsoletes',
              'weak_requires', 'info_requires',
              'weak_reverse_requires', 'info_reverse_requires', 
              'relativepath', 'hdrstart', 'hdrend', 'id',
              'checksum', 'pkgid', 'committer', 'committime',
              'ui_evr', 'evr', 'ui_nevra', 'ui_envra',
              'ui_from_repo', 'base_package_name', 'size', 'xattr_origin_url',
              'ui_evra', 'ui_nevr', 'na', 'vr', 'vra', 'evr', 'evra',
              'nvr', 'nvra', 'nevr', 'nevra', 'envr', 'envra',

              'repo.<attr of the repo object>',
              'yumdb.<attr of the yumdb object>',
              '<attr of the yum object>'
            ]
```

Noting `nvra` (name-ver-rel.arch) and `yumdb.<attr>` tags I am able to query `yumdb` for the full name and `reason` of each leaf passed in.

I can then do basic `grep` and `sed` to extract just the package name that I can store in an array.

```
package-cleanup --leaves -q --all | xargs repoquery --installed --qf '%\{nvra} - %\{yumdb_info.reason}' | grep -- '- dep' | sed "s/\s.*$//"
```

Using this array I was able to step through and set each item's `reason` to `user` so `yum autoremove -y` will not delete what I intended to be there.

```
yumdb set reason user $array_item
```

Or if you want the mother of all bash one liners...

```
array=$(package-cleanup --leaves -q --all | xargs repoquery --installed --qf '%{nvra} - %{yumdb_info.reason}' | grep -- '- dep' | sed "s/\s.*$//"); a=($array); if [ ${#a[@]} -gt "0" ]; then for i in "${array[@]}"; do yumdb set reason user $i; done; fi
```